# Work is a path function: it cannot be expressed as a difference between the value of some property of the system in two states

Tags: thermodynamics, work, conservative-field

Why do we not define work done as the difference between two quantities that depend entirely on the initial and final states.

Why is work a path function? What is the reason?

Comment: How would you propose to define this quantity "that depends entirely the initial and final states"? How would it work for non-[conservative forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force)?

Answer (score 1):

If work done (and hence change in energy) is a function of initial and final states of a system alone then the work done in any loop (when initial and final states are the same) is zero. This is true when the only forces acting on a system are conservative forces.

But in general there will be non-conservative forces (such as friction, air resistance, or non-elastic collisions) and energy will be lost in any loop. In this case work done cannot be a function of initial and final states only, but must be path dependent.

Comment: More I'mportantly, there is heat exchange in many processes.  Only the difference between the heat exchange and work is a function of the initial and final states, not the heat and work individually.

Answer (score 1):

> why this work is a path function?what is the reason?

Since the main tag for your post is thermodynamics, I will answer from that perspective.

The reason is the amount of work done between two equilibrium states depends on the path between the states. In the case of the expansion or compression of a gas, the work done between two equilibrium states equals the area under the PV diagram.

Refer to the diagrams below.

In the diagram to the left the path involves a constant pressure expansion to reach a final volume, then a constant volume heat extraction to reach the final pressure.

In the diagram to the right, we start with a constant volume heat extraction to reach the final pressure followed by a constant pressure expansion to reach the final volume.

Clearly the area under the first diagram is greater than the area under the second diagram, which shows that the work done between two states depends on the path.

Hope this helps.

[image]